# PHP - sometime getimagesize exchange the dimension of the image

Tags: php, symfony, image-size, getimagesize

I am using Symfony2 and I have a problem with the *PHP:getimagesize* because sometime the dimensions that this function return are exchanged.

My use of this function is like int the http://php.net/manual/es/function.getimagesize.php page and the images are sent to the server with a *POST*;

I post a mwe :

```
//INITIALIZATION OF VARIABLES
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
     if ($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i]) {
         $img = strtolower(strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s')) . $random . ".jpg");
         if (!is_dir($Tmppath)) {
              mkdir($Tmppath, 0777, TRUE);
         }
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i], $Tmppath . $img);
         if (file_exists($Tmppath . $img)) {
              if (!empty($img)) {
                   //DO SOMEHTING
                   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($Tmppath . $img);
                   //DO SOMEHTING
               }
          }
     }
}
```

But sometime the *$width* and *$height* of the image are exchanged; the images that are uploaded from the clients are of many format and sometime if the same image that is uploaded twice the width and height are exchanged. Anyone has the same problem? there is another function in *PHP* more precise?

Thanks

Comment: Do you take the EXIF orientation into account?